# NgRx root state key in app state interface

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

The following example of a selector is taken from the NgRx documentation:

```
import { createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';

export interface FeatureState {
    counter: number;
}

export interface AppState {
    feature: FeatureState;
}

export const selectFeature = (state: AppState) => state.feature;

export const selectFeatureCount = createSelector(
    selectFeature,
    (state: FeatureState) => state.counter
);
```

This is not working for me **unless** I also include the key of the root state defined in app.module.ts. E.g. if I define the following in app.module.ts:

```
StoreModule.forRoot({rootKey: reducer}),
```

My selector only works if this is included:

```
export const selectFeature = (state: AppState) => state.rootKey.feature;
```

However this then throws an error because I have deviated from my AppState interface.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I config

```
export interface State {
    router: fromRouter.RouterReducerState<any>;
}

export const ROOT_REDUCERS = new InjectionToken<
    ActionReducerMap<State, Action>
>("Root reducers token", {
    factory: () => ({
        router: fromRouter.routerReducer
    })
});

export function logger(reducer: ActionReducer<State>): ActionReducer<State> {
    return (state: State, action: any): any => {
        const result = reducer(state, action);
        console.groupCollapsed(action.type);
        console.log("prev state", state);
        console.log("action", action);
        console.log("next state", result);
        console.groupEnd();

        return result;
    };
}

export const metaReducers: Array<MetaReducer<State>> = !environment.production
    ? [logger]
    : [];
```

In my app.module.ts

```
StoreModule.forRoot(ROOT_REDUCERS, {
  metaReducers,
  runtimeChecks: {
    strictStateImmutability: true,
    strictActionImmutability: true,
    strictStateSerializability: true,
    strictActionSerializability: true,
  },
}),
```